# Subtract pattern matching from array element perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, pattern-matching, subtraction

I have written a code which allows me to subtract a specific value (ex: FP=0.021) from one element from an array if it matches a specific pattern. Here it is the code:

```
if ($info =~ /FP=/) {
            my @array1 = split(';', $info);
                if ($array1[$#array1] =~ /=([^.]*)/){
                    my $name1= $-[1];
                    $FPvalue = substr($array1[$#array1], $name1);
                    if ($FPvalue < 0.0001){ 
                        push(@FPvalues,$FPvalue);
```

Where $info is a string which contains information separated by a semicolon character (;).

I am lucky and the "FP=0.021" element is the last element from my array. But I would like to know a way for subtract it without using the expression: $array1[$#array1]

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: well, one way would be to pop it off the stack of the array, though that is really a cheap hack and only for this instance of getting rid of the "last" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without sample input data, but I think you want

```
push @FPvalues, $1 if $info =~ /FP=([\d.]+)/
```

It works by searching the string in `$info` for the sequence `FP=` followed by a number of dots and decimal digits. If that pattern is found, then the dots and digits part is put into `$1` and pushed onto the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can parse the decimal number from the string as it resides at the end of the string:

```
$str = "asdsa;adsasd;adsasd;FP=0.021";
if($str =~ /=(\d+\.?\d+)$/){
    print $1;
}
```